# How do I avoid require relative in my Rails 4 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

How do I avoid calling in my rspec model test in Rails 4.2.5 app?

I have `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` in application.rb

Yet without using require_relative as below in my rspec model test (spec/models/other_test_spec.rb) I can't seem to load the FileService class:

```
require_relative '../../lib/adapter/file_service'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your have added `lib` to your autoload path, not `lib/adapter`. When looking for `FileService` class, rails will only scan the autoload folders without looking into autoload subfolders. Subfolders are used for constants scoped within named modules.

Solution - rename your class to be `Adapter::FileService`. If this is too much work already, you might want to add `lib/adapter` to your autoload path as well.